# android - arabic font does not show very well

Tags: android, fonts

I wanna make an android app in arabic language and I need some complex font like

AdobeArabic-Regular.ttf. but this font has crashed and does not show letters correctly.what do I do???

Answer (score 0):

A .ttf should work. However, you have not provided any code. Check if this problem is the same for all custom fonts you use. If so, your implementation may be incorrect. I would then suggest checking out this tutorial: [Custom font guide.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_fonts.htm)

Comment: thanks for answering . I do not know the font file has problem or not but when I use the font such as the method in your link ,letters has little space between them or some letters are not correct

Comment: @faezesaghafi Having said "letters has little space between them or some letters are not correct". This issue seems to be due to Android itself when rendering complex fonts but was meant to have been fixed after 4.2.